# Did Heisuke Todo recruit those criminals as Shinsengumi replacements because he saw some skills in them, or did he just get what was available?

Tags: bucchigire

In Bucchigire, Heisuke Todo recruits 7 criminals as replacements of Shinsengumi members who were assasinated. But some members seem to have no superb combat skills at all, like Suzuran.

Did Heisuke Todo recruit those criminals as Shinsengumi replacements because he saw some skills in them, or did he just get what he could?